# Make description text slide up to 100% height of div

Tags: html, css, transition

I have an image block with an absolute positioned description sitting at the bottom. I want it when I hover over the description it slides up to the top in a transition and covers the whole image.

Here is my code just now.

```
<div class="offers-carousel-inner-default">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/550x500">
    <div class="offerDetails">
        <div class="content">
            <p>
      test
      </p>
            <a href="#" class="button col2-button">
                test
            </a>
        </div>
        <h5>
            test
        </h5>
    </div>

</div>

.offers-carousel-inner-default {
  position:relative;
  line-height:1;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
.offerDetails {
    position:absolute;
    padding:19px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:0;
    transition:all 0.4s linear;
    top:initial;
    font-family:"nobel-regular";
}
.offerDetails:hover {
    top:0;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.offerDetails:hover .content {
    display:block;
    order:2;
}
.offerDetails:hover .content-arrow {
    order:2;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.offerDetails h5 {
    font-size:20px;
    margin:0;
}
.offerDetails p {
    font-size:16px;
}
.offerDetails .content {
    display:none;
}
.offerDetails .content-arrow {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    transition:all 0.4s linear;
}
.offerDetails .content-arrow img {
    max-width:34px;
}
```

would be nice to do something like "top:0" and it would slide to the top and back down on hover.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinhwan/L0tncyvu/)

Comment: You may want to look into `max-height` with `overflow: hidden` and toggling those on the `.content` when they hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to keep the element on the bottom of its container and animate the element's height so that it goes from a fixed height value to `height: 100%`:

```css
.offers-carousel-inner-default {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.offerDetails {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 19px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  top: initial;
  font-family: "nobel-regular";
  height: 20px;
}

.offerDetails:hover {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.offerDetails:hover .content {
  display: block;
  order: 2;
}

.offerDetails:hover .content-arrow {
  order: 2;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.offerDetails h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.offerDetails p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.offerDetails .content {
  display: none;
}

.offerDetails .content-arrow {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.offerDetails .content-arrow img {
  max-width: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offers-carousel-inner-default">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/550x500">
  <div class="offerDetails">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        test
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="button col2-button">
                test
            </a>
    </div>
    <h5>
      test with height: 20px
    </h5>
  </div>

</div>
```

This won't work if you need to use `height:auto;` (because it doesn't work with `transition-duration`), though. In that case you can use `min-height`:

```css
.offers-carousel-inner-default {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.offerDetails {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 19px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  top: initial;
  font-family: "nobel-regular";
  height: auto;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.offerDetails:hover {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.offerDetails:hover .content {
  display: block;
  order: 2;
}

.offerDetails:hover .content-arrow {
  order: 2;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.offerDetails h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.offerDetails p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.offerDetails .content {
  display: none;
}

.offerDetails .content-arrow {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.offerDetails .content-arrow img {
  max-width: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offers-carousel-inner-default">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/550x500">
  <div class="offerDetails">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        test
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="button col2-button">
                test
            </a>
    </div>
    <h5>
      test with height:auto
    </h5>
  </div>

</div>
```